# Django - can not send email to multiple recipients

Tags: django, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to send mail to multiple recipients but I keep getting this error validation:

[image]

I'm using `django-multi-email-field` package and not certain this solution would help.

Please, see where I went wrong and guide me the right way.

Really appreciate your help!

Django: 1.10 and Python: 3.6

---

mail.py

```
from multi_email_field.forms import MultiEmailField


class mailHandler(forms.Form):
   subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
   receiver = MultiEmailField(label='Send to')
   message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50}),
                          required=False)


   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(mailHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper()
       self.helper.form_method = 'post'
       self.helper.form_class = 'form'
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Field(
               None,
               Div(
                   HTML('''
                          {% if messages %}
                          {% for message in messages %}
                          <center><p {% if message.tags %}
                          class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}"
                          {% endif %}>{{ message }}
                          <button type="button" name="message" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></p>
                          </center>{% endfor %}{% endif %}
                           '''),
                   Div('subject',
                       Field('receiver', placeholder='Email address',
                             required=True),
                       'message',
                       FormActions(
                           Submit('submit', 'Send', css_class='btn btn-lg btn-block'),
                       ),
                       ),
               ),
           ),
       )
```

---

views.py

```
class mailPost(FormView):
   success_url = '.'
   form_class = mailHandler
   template_name = 'post/post.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
       messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Email Sent!')
       return super(mailPost, self).form_valid(form)

   def form_invalid(self, form):
       messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING,
                         'Email not sent. Please try again.')
       return super(mailPost, self).form_invalid(form)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form_class = self.get_form_class()
       form = self.get_form(form_class)

       if form.is_valid():
           sender = "noreply@domain.com"    
           receiver = form.cleaned_data.get('receiver')
           subject = form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
           message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
           time = datetime.now()
           asoc_pk = Association.objects.filter(asoc_name=self.request.user.association)
           asoc = Association.objects.get(id=asoc_pk)

           Email.objects.create(
               sender=sender,
               receiver=receiver,
               subject=subject,
               message=message,
               association=asoc,
               sentTime=time
           )

           msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, sender, [receiver])
           msg.send()

           return self.form_valid(form)
       else:
           return self.form_invalid(form)
```

---

models.py

```
class Email(models.Model):
   sender = models.CharField(max_length=254)
   sentTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=254)
   receiver = models.CharField(max_length=254)
   message = models.TextField()
   association = models.ForeignKey(Association)

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Email'
```

Comment: i guess the problem is with your python version, as up till 3.5 is supported by multi email, you can try this in 3.5 or 3.4 to check if the problem persist or not

Comment: @Exprator - Sorry it did'nt work with either versions. Thanks for the advice =)

Comment: how about you try with a valid email address, like your email address and someones email address you know

Comment: @Exprator - also tried it and still no luck =p